# tar exclude not working within the bash

Tags: bash, tar

I can't get to work tar exclude with the bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash


CMD='tar --exclude=*.{db,log,token} -zcvf /home/pi/backup/2020.11.08-18.04.59.backup.tgz -P /home/pi/backup/test'
echo $CMD
sudo $CMD
```

however, if I ran the echo output command, it works.

tar --exclude=*.{db,log,token} -zcvf /home/pi/backup/2020.11.08-18.04.59.backup.tgz -P /home/pi/backup/test

I'm trying to exclude files based on file extension.

tar (GNU tar) 1.30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash you should use an array:

```
cmd=(tar --exclude='*'.{db,log,token} -zcvf /home/pi/backup/2020.11.08-18.04.59.backup.tgz -P /home/pi/backup/test)

echo "${cmd[@]}"

=> tar --exclude=*.db --exclude=*.log --exclude=*.token ...

"${cmd[@]}"
# etc
```

The `'*'` above is to guard against someone planting files named like `--exclude=foo.log`, `--exclude=bar.log` in the your current directory in order to trip your command ;-)

Notice that this has nothing to do with tar, but with your shell (bash) and with how it parses and expands its command lines; also, neither arrays nor brace expansions like `{db,log,...}` are supported in other shells like dash or busybox sh.

Comment: if I want to pass the db,log,token as variable, how do I use it
EXC=db,log,token
cmd=(tar --exclude='*'.{$EXC} -zcvf

Comment: I would not use brace expansion at all in that case. `exc=(db log token); cmd=(tar "${exc[@]/#/--exclude=*.}" ...); ...; "${cmd[@]}"`. What you're trying to do doesn't work because the brace expansion is performed before variable expansion in bash. You can make it work with `eval` but then you will have to double quote everything, turning it into a mess.